.NET Core ReactJS Deployment in AWS
When I deployed the Angular/React frontend and .NET Core docker backend in AWS EC2 Linux, there is an issue that the frontend can't call the backend using http:localhost:port inside ec2 locally.
Here are the details:

Deployed frontend in EC2 nginx
Setup application load balancer, listen http:80 and https:443
Get certificate of http://example.com from ACM
Cors setup in backend, but AWS needs to add https://example.com/ as allowed origins instead http://localhost:port in development mode
Set API url in frontend, this is the problem

In development mode, we setup http://localhost:port as backend API call, but in the production in AWS, frontend can't call backend API inside EC2, so we need to add URL as API call.
What I am doing:

Add https://example.com:port/ - the call get error timeout, event can't in postman
Add http://ec2-endpoint:port/ - the call get error with mix http and https call, but it can be called in postman

I want to know what is the solution for this type of application deployment, do we need subdomain like https://api.example.com for the backend call?
Is there any way we can let frontend and backend communicate inside ec2?
Any suggestion and tutorial link will be appreciated.

Is it working when you SSH into EC2 and check docker container?

Yes, the docker port works fine inside EC2 e.g. curl also using postman to ec2 URL

Have you checked the application log? What's detials error or warning message?
